# Multiple file upload

Tags: javascript, html, upload

Is there any way to upload more than 20 files with HTML5  file upload? Currently I am only able to upload 20 files at a time. I need to be able to upload about 100 to 200 images at once.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a script issue and not an HTML5 issue?

Comment: That's what I'm hoping to find out lol

Answer (score 2):

you can use the http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/ file uploader its such a good file uploader

its also very secure since it is using the [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) and [Cross-site Scripting (XSS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) also disabled it also  [prevent arbitrary files](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Security)

also check this [link](http://stevesouders.com/hpws/max-connections.php) to know the limit of browsers connection at a time

Comment: Awesome I'll play around with it. Thanks

Comment: If the browser won't natively allow more than 20 files, how can a jQuery plugin work around that? *edit* ah I think it may be the case that there really is no such limit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will help you.

But I would suggest uploading a zip and then extracting server side. It will be harder to validate the content though.

Comment: No I need the photographer to upload the images. I'm not sure how the zip file will work. Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you use PHP. This platform has a limitation on files count in one POST request. It is equal to 20 :) To increase this value you should open php.ini, find max_file_uploads and set it to a large number, e.g. 2000.